# Binding label's value to the count property of an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, nsarraycontroller

I want to show in a label the current number of elements in an NSArray called pages. Following other guides  I did the following:

1. Created an NSArrayController in IB (called pagesController) and bounded it to the NSArray pages
2. Bounded the value property of the label to the NSArrayController with Controller Key = arrangedObjects and Model Key Path = @count

The problem is that when the program is running the label always shows "0". To check if the things are working correctly I tried to log a message when the user clicks on another button (the button basically inserts a new element in the pages array): `NSLog(@"count = %d", [self.pagesController valueForKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.@count"]);` in this case the output is correct, i.e. the current number of elements in the array printed is correct.
Where am I mistaking?

Comment: some code would be better to understand, where u r getting wrong?

Comment: What "other guides" did you follow? When I google I only find this question.

Answer (score 0):

You many not be using KVC correctly. Your array controller will only be notified with the `pages` property is redefined, not when objects are added to the array. Try wrapping your code with the appropriate change notifications:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"pages"];
[pages addObject:someObject];
[self didChangeValueFOrKey:@"pages"];
```